# Partitioning the data based on column values

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, apache-pig, partitioning

Hi I have data source as following

```
ID       Date            Page

100      27-10-2015     google
102      27-10-2015     facebook
102      27-10-2015     instagram
104      28-10-2015     yahoo
105      30-10-2015     bing
```

I want to store this data in parquet format with the form as shown below

```
/foldername/columname=value/data.parquet
```

For eg here

```
/output/ID=102/data.parquet
/output/ID=104/data.parquet
```

Here data.parquet contains values of the column ID=102 in parquet format.

Can any one help me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Using DataFrames your code should look like this:

```
val df = yourData
df.write.partitionBy(['ID']).format("parquet").save(dest, mode="append")
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your data source is table : `t1`
The following SQL will create you the table you want :

```
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;

CREATE TABLE T1_PRQT (date string,page string) 
PARTITIONED BY (id int)
STORED AS parquet
LOCATION '/output';

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE T1_PRQT PARTITION(id) 
SELECT date,page,id FROM T1;
```

First line enables creating dynamic partitions upon insert
The Create SQL creates a table, with fields `date,page,id` when the `id` is the partition column, file format is `parquet` and its stored in `/output`.
The Insert SQL, loads the data from your previous table `t1` to the new one.